# Get VPS real CPU frequency and RAM size

Tags: linux, vps, windows

Is there any way to get VPS real CPU frequency and RAM size (I'm interested in both Linux and Windows)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh sorry, I didn't read the question thoroughly. But I guess, you can guess it using the information provided in the linux. But this is not accurate, because per definition of virtualizing hardware, one can "fake" all the information provided.

Assuming you have direct linux ssh access to the VPS

### Get CPU/RAM information

You can use:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

to get the CPU speed and it's "origin"

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 2
model name  : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.12.3
stepping    : 3
cpu MHz     : 3074.290
cache size  : 4096 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 4
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm up rep_good pni cx16 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips    : 6148.58
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

to get the Ram size you can simply type:

```
free -m
```

which will show you this output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1003        177        826          0         14        130
-/+ buffers/cache:         31        971
Swap:         2053          0       2053
```

Interestingly, the lshw command shows a bit different information:

```
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.12.3
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 401
      bus info: cpu@0
      slot: CPU01
      size: 2GHz
      capacity: 2GHz
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx x86-64 up rep_good pni cx16 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 1000
      size: 1GiB
      capacity: 1GiB
    *-bank
         description: DIMM RAM
         physical id: 0
         slot: DIMM 0
         size: 1GiB
         width: 64 bits
```

### Guess the CPU

Looking at the bogomips, now we can use google to guess the maker of the CPU. With the bogomips we can start googling the CPU: In this case it seems to be, the

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz
```

I don't quite believe this. Since this from a VPS from hetzner.de.. But we're only getting a single CPU with 2ghz out of the 4 cores with 3.07 ghz each.

Comment: Unfortunately these commands return values for physical server, not for VPS.

Comment: No, I believe, I got the values that are being advertised from the server. From what I can see, the lshw command returns the values corresponding to the VPS. Nothing wrong with that. In my opinion you can't really say each VPS is say getting 2ghz. From the Host CPU. Virtualization doesn't work that way. The workload is shared between all the machines that are running on the system and depending on the "share" they've been allocated with.